# Marker Manager not showing markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markermanager

I am having problems using the MarkerManager. Somehow Markers added with the MarkerManager do not show up, though i do `mgr.refresh();` It works when i use basic `map.addOverlay(marker);` but not when using `mgr.addMarker(marker);`. Weird. Hope someone here can help.

Here's the relevant code:

```
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(48.25, 11.00), 4);

    mgr = new MarkerManager(map, mgr_options);
    markers = createSpotMarkers(spots); // parsing spots, extending bounds, creating Array of GMarkers etc, pretty basic and seems not be relevant.
    mgr.addMarkers(markers); // does not work
    map.addOverlay(markers[0]); // works
    mgr.addMarker(markers[0]); // does not work either 

    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds)-1);
    mgr.refresh();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the API for MarkerManager [expects 3 arguments to addMarkers](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/release/docs/reference.html), of which the 3rd seems to be optional.  The second, however, doesn't.  If the API doesn't help, [then a blog post showing example usage might](http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/enhancing-your-google-maps-applications-with-markermanager-and-progressbarcontrol/).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that the second argument is mandatory.